# Will spring kafka API automatically attempt for reconnection in case of broker failure?

Tags: spring-kafka, broker, reconnect

I have a doubt regarding spring kafka broker failover mechanism. I was checking by bringing the brokers down, voluntarily and I've been getting these "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Brokers may not be available" warnings continuously as soon as the brokers went down. I understand that it's because of the broker unavailability. I want a support document to know that if it happens automatically by the API itself?

Answer (score 0):

This is all handled by the underlying kafka-clients code; it is outside of Spring's responsibility; Spring is not informed of the situation.

The client will reconnect when the brokers come back up.